# Ajax call to Dispatcher servlet

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc

I am trying to make a simple AJAX call to dispatcher servlet from JSP and get string as response.But,I am able to call dispatcher servlet using form tag in jsp and success page is getting called.If I use ajax call is not even reaching dispatcher servlet.Please find the code for reference.I just want to know whether am I doing it in a right way.My goal is to get AJAX response

test.jsp

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Tabs - Default functionality</title>
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn1").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "Post",  
            url: "hello",
            success: function(resp){
             alert(resp)
            }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type ="button" id="btn1" />
</body>
</html>
```

HelloController.java

```
package test;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public class HelloController{

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String printHello(ModelMap model) {
  return "success";
}
}
```

HelloWeb-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="test" />
<bean  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
   <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: Change url to `contextPath+/hello`

Answer (score 0):

**It doesn't matter if you're using Ajax call or not, the request should reach to the desired controller.**

With that being said, and the fact you wrote that the request doesn't even reach to its destination, then your problem is within your URL.

I would recommend using the ***Spring Url tag*** which is a part of Spring tag library. It will help you build your URL within your JSP files.

In your URL example, you obviously missing the complete URL, I believe it should be: `http://localhost:8080/your_project_name/hello`

So just do this:

1. add the next directive to your JSP file:

   `<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>`
2. use the spring url tag within you Ajax call:

`$.ajax
 ({
   type: "Post",
   url: '<spring:url value="/hello"/>',
   success: function(resp){
     alert(resp)
   }
  });`

So the final result of your JSP should be:

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery UI Tabs - Default functionality</title>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
    <script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#btn1").click(function(){
            $.ajax
              ({
                  type: "Post",
                  url: '<spring:url value="/hello"/>',
                  success: function(resp){
                     alert(resp)
                  }
               });
        });
      });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input type ="button" id="btn1" />
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I tried that code.Still the error persists.While trying this code,I was getting a erros like **java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: not in a DispatcherServlet request and no ContextLoaderListener registered?**  . So I added '<listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>' and '<context-param>
       <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/HelloWeb-servlet.xml</param-value>
      </context-param>' in web.xml